# Given moment about a pin and a roller

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, statics

sorry to ask, have not been a able to find a similar question to mine. [image: problem]

For this problem, given moment $M_2$, distances $a$ and $b$
My reasoning is that we have two support reactions and points *A* and *B*. Find the moment about each point; taking C-CW moment positive, the arrow for the reaction supports point $+y$ direction positive as well, 
point *A*: 
support reaction $y$ axis at point B = RB_y
RB_y*(a+b) - M2 = 0 ==> RB_y = M2 / (a+b)

point *B*: support reaction on y axis at point B = RA_y
-RA_y(a+b) - M2 = 0 ==> RA_y = M2/(a+b)

let me know if this makes sense, thanks all! 
Point B: Roller
Point: Pin

Answer (score 1):

### Statics

Sum of forces equals zero:

$$A_y + B_y = 0$$

Sum of moments (about *A*) equals zero:

$$ (a+b) B_y - M_2 = 0 $$

Two equations with two unknowns $A_y$ and $B_y$.

What is your questions again?